# Application start on Windowsstart with Parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, startup

I have programmed an Application, which puts your Directory to HTML. You have to put in three strings: the first for the where to safe Path, the second for the which Path should been put to HTML and the third for the name, which the first HTML file gets. 
[image: Picture of my Program on Start]
[image: Picture of the Result]

My Question now is, how can I make my program start on Windows startup and then give it the parameters to Update the HTML files? I somehow need to safe the paths in a file and read this on startup which then executes my program with these parameters.

Do you need any more information? I'm not sure if I was clear enought, but I hope on fast response.

Comment: "your directory" that sounds vague.. is this going to be a service you have running on your machine?

Comment: yeah i think soo...

Comment: then your parameters would be in your service setup.  however, it sounds like you wrote code without planning how you were using it.. "yeah I think so" sounds like you havent written c# code for a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to do 2 things:
First, you want to add your program to the startup. Therefore, follow: [how to add programs to startup](http://tunecomp.net/add-app-to-startup/)

Secondly, you might want to consider to use (app) config files, which are read by your program when it executes.